# Как распаковать 7z?

Tags: c#, 7z

Понадобилось собственными руками сделать установщик-распаковщик архива. Неважно, почему именно собственными руками.
Вот только никогда до этого я не делал приложений, распаковывающих архивы. Прочитал про 7z.dll (или 7-zip.dll?). В общем, я не понял, какую из них использовать и как.

Comment: Сам распаковщик писать хочешь или только оболочку? От этого зависит, пнуть тебя в сторону документации или библиотеки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно запустить 7zip с нужными параметрами:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe";
        processStartInfo.Arguments = @"e C:\test.7z";
        Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Пример взят [отсюда](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/849c4969-24b1-4650-88a5-5169727e527f/how-to-unzip-a-file-using-c-and-7zip-utility?forum=csharpgeneral)

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы воспользоваться 7z.dll нужна обертка в виду библиотеки [SevenZipSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SevenZipSharp/):

```
if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
{
    //x64
    SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll");
}
else
{
    //x86
    SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.dll");
}

using (var file = new SevenZipExtractor(pathToArchive))
{
    file.ExtractArchive(outputPath);  
}
```